# Android: ArithmeticException in StaggeredGridLayoutManager

Tags: java, android, crashlytics, staggered-gridview, fabric.io

My app works fine with almost android versions. But, in Crashlytics and in some devices, I have this crash: "java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero".  Its almost (if not always) in Android 4.x.

I have a StaggeredGridLayoutManager in a RecyclerView (SuperRecyclerView).

Stack trace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
   at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.updateMeasureSpecs(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:922)
   at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:665)
   at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:600)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3374)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3183)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3627)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14102)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4662)
   at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:630)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14102)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4662)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14102)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4662)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14102)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4662)
   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1142)
   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:836)
   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:850)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14102)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4662)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1799)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14102)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4662)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14102)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4662)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14102)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4662)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14102)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4662)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14102)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4662)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14102)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4662)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14102)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4662)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2019)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1840)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1135)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4579)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4935)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

I don't know what kind of information is needed to approach this problem, so please ask me whatever you need so I can update the question.

Comment: Any solution to this? I am currently receiving this same error. I'm even hard setting the SpanCount

Answer (score 0):

Saw it, too, but on Android 5 and 7 as well. I checked the code and apparently it crashes when mSpanCount is 0. Unlike `GridLayoutManager`, `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`'s `setSpanCount` doesn't check whether it's 1 or greater, and simply crashes later.
In my case, the span count was 0 because I made it depend on the screen size, which seems to be 0 in rare cases.